# default radio to yes in struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
<nested:radio property="sendFlag" value="Yes" onclick="showDiv();" />Yes<nested:radio property="sendFlag" value="No" onclick="hideDiv();" />No
```

The above code defaults to No, on my jsp. Is there a way in which I can allow the Yes button to be selected by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `ActionForm` where `sendFlag` attribute is found, do this:

```
private boolean sendFlag = true;
```

If that doesn't work, override the `reset()` method by setting the `sendFlag` to true.

That way, when Struts renders the `sendFlag`, it will tick it.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. Can you tell me how the function showDiv() be called now on default

Comment: @dazzle, I don't follow. Please explain.

Comment: Earlier whenever user clicked Yes radio button, the showDiv() function used to get called. Now as I have made the 'Yes' button enabled by default, the showDiv() function does not get called.

Comment: `showDiv()` on your code, is invoked when button is clicked. Now, you will have to check the radio button check on `document.onload` function and invoke `showDiv()`. I suggest creating a new question for this.